# Trabalhando com métodos/variaveis estáticos

Tags: python, django

Caros,

Ao chamar uma classe em python, as variáveis dessa classe sempre serão reiniciadas?

O que acontece é o seguinte: Estou trabalhando com a paralelização do meu código. Eu recebo os dados retornados do banco de dados, quebro eles em varios chunks e mando para o Celery esses chunks, para que ele processe e salve os resultados em uma lista. Para isso, tenho uma classe controladora que possui dois métodos estáticos. O primeiro deve salvar os valores que recebe em uma lista. O segundo deve pegar essa lista, ordenala e retornar o seu primeiro valor. Minha classe é a seguinte:

```
class chunkControler:

    value = []

    @staticmethod
    def setregisterpercent(registerpercent):
        __class__.value.append(registerpercent)

    @staticmethod
    def getvalue():
    __class__.value.sort()
    return __class__.value[0]
```

Para salvar os valores, eu chamo essa classe da seguinte forma na minha task:

```
from .chunkControler import chunkControler
chunkControler.setregisterpercent(registerpercent)
```

e para recuperar os valores, faço da seguinte forma na minha view:

```
from .chunkControler import chunkControler
resultado = chunkControler.getvalue()
    print(resultado)
```

(Os imports estão sendo feitos no inicio dos arquvios tasks.py e views.py)

O problema, é que quando chamo o método `chunkControler.getvalue()`, o retorno está sendo da lista vazia, como se uma nova lista fosse criada para este retorno. Existe alguma forma de burlar isso e retornar a lista que foi criada inicialmente?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/JampackedBriskCookies

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, meu programa está com a mesma estrutura, porém continuo a receber como retorno uma lista vazia. Acredito que deva então ser algum problema com o Celery.

Comment: Talvez você esteja tentando pegar os dados antes da hora (já que o celery é baseado em assincronismo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não armazene valores desta forma. A explicação é complexa, mas basicamente o django não funciona desta maneira, não se pode gravar variáveis "globais" nem armazenar nada em classes estáticas, isso é altamente não recomendado, ainda mais usando o celery.

Minha dica é, para guardar e resgatar valores utilize o banco, se esse valor não for tão "precioso" assim utilize cache. (recomendo o cache de memória porque é bem rápido)

```
cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)
cache.get('my_key')
```

[Django cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/)

No settings, utilize um backend a sua escolha, coloquei de exemplo o cache usando a memória local:

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```